# Java Import Static error

Tags: java, compilation

I have this import source :

```
import static   MinecraftDungeonTileTypes.*;
```

on class in same package as the class `MinecraftDungeonTileTypes`

source of class:

```
package mod.dungeonworld;

public  class MinecraftDungeonTileTypes {
    public static  int TILE_WALL = 0;
    public static  int TILE_ROAD = 1;
    public static  int TILE_DOOR = 2;
    public static  int TILE_CHEST = 3;
    public static  int TILE_ROOM = 4;
    public static  int TILE_COD = 5;
    public static  int TILE_SPAWNER = 6;
}
```

What I get Is an compilation error:

> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type The import
>   MinecraftDungeonTileTypes cannot be resolved.

When I use the static members of class `MinecraftDungeonTileTypes` regularly without static import I get no compile error. What is causing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't [statically import](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/static-import.html) a non `static` class but you can import statically it's `static` fields / attributes:

> In order to access static members, it is necessary to qualify references with the class they came from. For example, one must say:

Import single attribute (use `*` instead of name to import massively)

```
import static mod.dungeonworld.MinecraftDungeonTileTypes.TILE_WALL;
```

You will refer in the code as `TILE_WALL`.

Or import the class

```
import mod.dungeonworld.MinecraftDungeonTileTypes;
```

You will refern to same attribute in the code as `MinecraftDungeonTileTypes.TILE_WALL`.

Comment: *"You can't statically import a non static class but you can import statically it's static fields / attributes"* Nice info, but since OP doesn't do that, it is not really related to this question.

Answer (score 2):

The problem comes from that I haven't written the full path of the class I want to import. Here is solution in my case:

```
import static   mod.dungeonworld.MinecraftDungeonTileTypes.*;
```

Comment: @Hiru Why should he? Do you know what this page is for?

Comment: @Hiru What!? There are plenty of great self-answers on this website. In fact, it's actively encouraged to answer your own question when you find the answer!